# Appropriate title for a committee member responsible for monitoring conflicts of interest

Tags: terminology

This is in the context of a sporting body that has occasionally had problems with officers getting too friendly with business interests associated with the sport.

The body is thinking of creating a new seat on its committee to monitor and report on these conflicts of interest, but isn't sure what this person's title should be.

Comment: Main Snitch? Master Informer?

Answer (score 3):

The title for such folks is "Ethics and Compliance Officer," and they even have their own [association](http://www.theecoa.org/imis15/ECOAPublic/).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @deadrat said, consider **Compliance Officer** for a term that's shorter and bit more generic:

> compliance officer: a person who is employed to ensure that a company does not contravene any statutes or regulations which apply to its activities

(Oxford Dictionary)

Or **chief ethics officer**:

> **Chief ethics officers** started appearing in corporate hallways in 1991, when the Federal Sentencing Guidelines for corporations went into effect.

([forbes.com](http://www.forbes.com/2006/10/23/leadership-ethics-hp-lead-govern-cx_hc_1023ethics.html))

Or simply **ethics officer**:

> Ethics Officer: The ethics officer serves as the organization’s internal control point for ethics and improprieties, allegations, complaints and **conflicts of interest** and provides corporate leadership and advice on corporate governance issues.

([www.shrm.org](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:bPBS0ioNIRMJ:www.shrm.org/templatestools/samples/jobdescriptions/pages/cms_014713.aspx%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk))